# Working with recursive function in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, drop-down-menu, while-loop

I have code like this. This will display all the menu,sub-menu, sub-sub-menus etc.. in an order.

Now, I need to add a checkbox button to each menu (main-menu, sub-menu etc) and once the checkbox is checked and the form is submitted, I need to store the
menu ids in my db. How can I do that?

Any help with the below code will be very helpful.

```
    <div align="center">Access Rights for Authos</div>
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("booksdb") or die(mysql_error());
    menu_level_function_recursive(0);
    function menu_level_function_recursive($parent)
    {
    global $data;
    global $get_final_list;
    $get_menu_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu where parent_menu_id=".$parent." order by menu_order");
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php 
    for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($get_menu_query);$i++)
    {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $get_menu_query );
    $get_sub_menu_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu where parent_menu_id=".$row['m_id']." order by menu_order");
    ?>
    <li><a href='<?php echo $row['menu_url'] ?>'><?php echo $row['menu_name'] ?>
    <?php 
    if(mysql_num_rows($get_sub_menu_query)>0)
    {
    menu_level_function_recursive($row['m_id']);
    }
    ?>
    </a>
    </li> 
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

In short, show check box to each menu, and once the check box is checked, or unchecked, dump the values to database.

Comment: create form, add checkboxes like this `<input type="checkbox" name="id[ID GOES HERE]">` and you will get nice array with id's checked from `array_keys($_POST['id'])`

Comment: You are using the deprecated extension `mysql_*` and don't use `globals`.